# How to integrate sorl-thumbnail into an existing django project?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to integrate sorl-thumbnail into an existing project to show thumbnails of ImageField photos in the django admin, however am having no results.

I installed sorl using

```
pip install sorl-thumbnail
```

then added

```
'sorl.thumbnails'
```

to settings.py

then ran `manage.py syncdb`, then set up admin.py with

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin

class MyModelAdmin(AdminImageMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Though I still don't see a thumbnail on my django admin when viewing the listing for `MyModel` or when I look at each individual `MyModel`

What am I doing wrong?

nb: I am using South for migrations and S3 to store the static images for my app

Comment: Can you verify that the sorl-thumbnail widget is actually being used? (i.e view source on the admin page and see if there's an `img` tag next to the field.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AdminImageMixin` changes the widget for the `ImageField` only if it's an instance of *sorl-thumbnail's* `ImageField`. So your model needs to use the following:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_image = ImageField(...)
```

Instead of `django.db.models.ImageField`.

If you've done that, the `img` tag for the thumbnail should be being added next to the field in the admin source, if it is in fact in the source, it might be an issue with storing the files on S3 and the URL being used by sorl-thumbnail doesn't match.

Comment: I have `from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField` in the model, and on the admin page I have the following code:

`<div>
        <label for="id_photo" class="required">Photo:</label>   
        <p class="file-upload">Currently: <a href="https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/3.jpeg">photos/3.jpeg</a> <br />Change: <input type="file" name="photo" id="id_photo" />
  </p>   
</div>`

ie: no image field.  I'm looking at the `kvstore` table on my postgres and there are no rows there, do you think that is a problem?  Such a great addon to django though I wish there were more docs.

Comment: Staring at this code for far too long had been using `models.ImageField` rather than `ImageField`, which (obviously) solved the problem.  As an addition for any interested readers there seem to be no problems integrating S3 and sorl-thumbnail